# SQL Sum duration by hour and day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query that will convert a duration field into seconds and then sum the durations based on what time and day it is.

The duration is the amount of time that the "event" was running during the hour of the end date.

I have this:

```
Description | Start Date              | End Date                | Duration
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC         | 2015-08-17 10:30:30.000 | 2015-08-17 11:59:59.000 | 0 00:59:59.0
ABC         | 2015-08-18 11:00:00.000 | 2015-08-18 11:30:00.000 | 0 00:30:00.0
DEF         | 2015-08-17 08:25:00.000 | 2015-08-17 10:30:00.000 | 0 00:30::00.0
ABC         | 2015-08-18 11:30:00.000 | 2015-08-18 11:59:59.000 | 0 00:29:59.0
```

And I'm trying to get something like this:

```
Description | Date       | Hour | Duration
-------------------------------------------
ABC         | 2015-08-17 | 11   | 3575
ABC         | 2015-08-18 | 11   | 3575
DEF         | 2015-08-17 | 10   | 1800
```

This is the query I have wrote:

```
SELECT Description,
       DATEPART(HOUR, EndDT), SUM(DATEPART(SECOND, CONVERT(TIME, RIGHT(Duration, LEN(Duration) -2))) +
       60 * DATEPART(MINUTE, CONVERT(TIME, RIGHT(Duration, LEN(Duration) - 2))) +
       3600 * DATEPART(HOUR, CONVERT(TIME, RIGHT(Duration, LEN(Duration) - 2))))
FROM table
GROUP BY Description,
         DATEPART(HOUR, EndDT),
         DATEADD(d, 0, DATEDIFF(d, 0, EndDT));
```

This query doesn't seem to be taking days into consideration like I thought it would and I have no idea how fix it.

I am getting something like this:

```
Description | Hour | Duration
------------------------------
ABC         | 11   | 7150
DEF         | 10   | 1800
```

I also realise that I haven't got the date in the select statement at the moment, but that can be added later.

Comment: Do you want the hours to round up or down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `GROUP` your data by EndDT date part only, you get what you need:

```
WITH T AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('ABC', CAST('2015-08-17 10:30:30.000' AS DATETIME), CAST('2015-08-17 11:59:59.000' AS DATETIME), '0 00:59:59.0'),
                ('ABC', CAST('2015-08-18 11:00:00.000' AS DATETIME), CAST('2015-08-18 11:30:00.000' AS DATETIME), '0 00:30:00.0'),
                ('DEF', CAST('2015-08-17 08:25:00.000' AS DATETIME), CAST('2015-08-17 10:30:00.000' AS DATETIME), '0 00:30:00.0'),
                ('ABC', CAST('2015-08-18 11:30:00.000' AS DATETIME), CAST('2015-08-18 11:59:59.000' AS DATETIME), '0 00:29:59.0'))
            AS V(Description, StartDT, EndDT, Duration)
) 
SELECT  Description ,
        CAST(EndDT AS DATE),
        DATEPART(HOUR, EndDT) ,
        SUM(DATEPART(SECOND, CONVERT(TIME, RIGHT(Duration, LEN(Duration) - 2)))
            + 60 * DATEPART(MINUTE,CONVERT(TIME, RIGHT(Duration, LEN(Duration) - 2)))
            + 3600 * DATEPART(HOUR, CONVERT(TIME, RIGHT(Duration, LEN(Duration) - 2))))
FROM    T
GROUP BY 
        Description ,
        CAST(EndDT AS DATE),
        DATEPART(HOUR, EndDT)
```

For this i am getting:

```
ABC 2015-08-17  11  3599
ABC 2015-08-18  11  3599
DEF 2015-08-17  10  1800
```

You can ignore the `CTE` that holds data from the example above, just added it to provide a working example.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you how many hours and seconds each event was running for each day.

```
SELECT Description,
DATEDIFF(s,MIN([Start Date]), MAX([End Date]))/60/60 AS Hour,
DATEDIFF(s,MIN([Start Date]), MAX([End Date])) AS Duration
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Description, DAY([Start Date])
```

OUTPUT

```
Description  Hour   Duration
ABC          1      5369
DEF          2      7500
ABC          0      3599
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/935c7/15/0